# 2 methods , same name ,different input , how elude and if/else writing?

Tags: java, input, methods

*I learned that it is possible to use 2 methods with the same name in the same class, as long as they differ in the format of the input.*

Let's assume that I wrote a method `D` that takes `int` as an input and another `D` method that takes `(int, int)` as an input.

**My question is:**
When I invoke the method `D` from the main class, how can I make it possible for the user to insert one or 2 int's as he wishes, without me writing an if/else lines that trace down if the user inserted 1 or 2 int's?

Comment: You write if / else or other control blocks (e.g.., switch / case) as needed. Why not?

Comment: surely i understand that i can write these,

Comment: question is is there a shorter way without if/else

Comment: Again why? Again, not that I know of.

Comment: thats the answer i have being looking for... thank's a lot

Comment: If the methods return the same type (say Boolean) you can do `boolean b = length == 1 ? D(int) : D(int, int);` but this is just syntax sugar to `if else` statement.

Comment: Another option is to make just one `D(int... data)`.